New command optional arguments for sub, supra, and argument of an operator
I'm trying to specify a command that allows to display an operator, its evaluation at a certain argument, and add sub and supra indexes. That is, the commands
\f
\f{a}
\f{a}{i}
\f{a}{i}{j}

Should return f, f(a), f_i(a), and f_i^j(a).
So far I've tried the following
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\f}{ggg}{%
\operatorname{\mathrm{f}}%
\IfValueT{#1}{\lb #1\rb}%
\IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}%
\IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}}%
}

but I get f(a)_i^j after typing \f{a}{i}{j}, and I don't want to change the order of the arguments. Do you know a better approach?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried to reorder the ifs, putting \IfValueT{#1}{\lb #1\rb} last?

note all of xparse apart from g  is now included in latex by default. g was left out and deprecated with good reason.  Optional arguments with {} don't fit latex syntax. A more standard latex syntax with be to use e not g and then \f_{i}{a], or if you prefer \f{a}_{i}

Don't use the g argument type: it's deprecated. Besides, you'd need empty arguments if the subscript is missing and it's difficult to remember the order of arguments.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\f}{oe{_^}}{%
  \operatorname{f}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}%
  ^{\IfValueTF{#3}{#3}{}}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{(#1)}%
}

\begin{document}

$\f$
$\f[a]$
$\f_i$
$\f^j$
$\f_i^j$
$\f^j_i$
$\f[a]_i$
$\f[a]^j$
$\f[a]_i^j$
$\f[a]^j_i$

\end{document}



Thanks! That was exactly what I needed. Didn't know g was deprecated.
